# thickbox loads very slowly in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, thickbox

I'm using a thickbox to display the response from an http request. When the response is huge, the internet explorer takes about 35-40 seconds to display the thickbox popup while in Chrome, it only takes 2-3 seconds.

I'm using Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: how is the benchmark without the thickbox, comparing both browsers? might have nothing to do with the thickbox, but with rendering engines of different browsers?